# Convert array Students to stream<String>

Tags: java, java-stream

I need convert an array of Students into a String stream of the following type:
"Mike: [4, 5, 3]" ( name and all marks in parentheses). Don't use the toString method.

```java
Map<String, List<Integer>> markAnn = new HashMap<>();
markAnn.put("Physics", List.of(4,4,5));
markAnn.put("Mathematics", List.of(2,3,4));

Map<String, List<Integer>> markKate = new HashMap<>();
markKate.put("Physics", List.of(1,2,3));
markKate.put("Mathematics", List.of(5,5,3));

Stud7[] students = {
    new Stud7("Ann", markAnn),
    new Stud7("Kate", markKate)
};
```

I tried to create two streams and combine them and output them immediately in the method peek(), but it doesn't work. I just started learning stream =(

```java
class Lesson7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<Integer>> markAnn = new HashMap<>();
        markAnn.put("Physics", List.of(4,4,5));
        markAnn.put("Mathematics", List.of(2,3,4));

        Map<String, List<Integer>> markKate = new HashMap<>();
        markKate.put("Physics", List.of(1,2,3));
        markKate.put("Mathematics", List.of(5,5,3));

        Stud7[] students = { new Stud7("Ann", markAnn),
                             new Stud7("Kate", markKate) };

        String[] strings = new String[students.length]; 
        Stream<String> StreamName = Arrays.stream(students).map(Stud7::getName);
        Stream<Integer>StreamMarks = Arrays.stream(students)
                .flatMap(s -> s.getMarks().values().stream())
                .flatMap(Collection::stream);
        Stream.concat(StreamName, StreamMarks).
    }

    private static class Stud7 {
        private String name;
        private Map<String, List<Integer>> marks;

        public Stud7(String name, Map<String, List<Integer>> marks) {
            this.name = name;
            this.marks = marks;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public Map<String, List<Integer>> getMarks() {
            return marks;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What should happen to the various entries in the map inside a `Stud7` object? Output it once per entry, so the students name gets put multiple time to the stream? Or only take one specific entry with a given key? Or perform some calculation of the marks? Or something completely different?

Comment: *I need convert an array of Students into a String stream of the following type: "Mike: [4, 5, 3]"* How then will you know for what subject those are the marks?

Comment: "*Don't use the `toString` method*" does it also apply to each separate mark which is Integer? Do you need to create your own method which for `1` will return `"1"` etc.?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```java
Arrays.stream(students)
  .map(student -> student.getName() + " " + student.getMarks().values())
```

Alternatively, you can use `Map#entrySet` to create a string containing the subjects with their respective marks.

Comment: thank you, you helped me a lot. I thought there was something complicated there ))

Comment: @KtoTam Note that `student.getMarks().values()` is implicitly `student.getMarks().values().toString()`. Is that allowed since in question you mentioned to "Don't use the toString method". Also this would result in something like `Ann [[2, 3, 4], [4, 4, 5]]`. Is that format what you wanted?

Comment: @Pshemo true, I wrote this answer assuming that only `Stud7`'s toString has to be avoided, but reading it again, I'm honestly not that sure anymore    |  I'll update the answer to be more accurate once the OP clarifies these things

Comment: Ann [[2, 3, 4], [4, 4, 5]] this answer is correct. the main thing is that the tostring method is not called explicitly.

Comment: @KtoTam if that’s the requirement, you can always replace `o.toString()` with `"" + o`…